# Manage UDDI registry with CXF

Tags: soap, cxf, uddi

I have an application using Apache CXF with a lots of SOAP services implemented. So, i would like to use the "service registry" concept and then, i´d hear about UDDI, but i dont know how to implemented that.

Is Apache CXF already composed by an API to deploy UDDI engine or should i fix another library to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at JUDDI:

http://juddi.apache.org/

which is a UDDI service.  The latest version is written to JAX-WS and is tested by default with CXF.

Answer (score 0):

To add, jUDDI has a neat way to automate the registration of web services using annotations and a servlet startup listener.

Source: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/juddi/trunk/juddi-examples/uddi-annotations/